# Android viewProperty animation issues

Tags: android, animation

HI i have the below animation for a view below:

```
    val duration = 2000L
    val visible = 1.0f
    imageAVater.apply {
            animate().translationYBy(-100f).alpha(visible).setDuration(duration).setListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter(){
                override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
                    visibility = View.VISIBLE
                   
                }
            })
        }
```

i want it to move from slightly off-position and into position and to also reveal itself by setting the alpha .

SO far neither works.

ALl the code above does is move the image from current default position on my layout(lets say i positioned it in xml along the Y axis position 200) and then it moves from position 200 to position 100 and also the alpha does not work, the item is visible all the time despite it being set to View.Gone in my xml

```
 android:visibility="gone"
```

How can i set a start and end Y axis value for this translation animation and how can i get the alpha to work so that the view appears from hidden/gone?

i want it to start at 200 y and have it transition to 100 y and to also reveal itself from being hidden/gone to being shown at the same time as the transition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify starting values for y and alpha. EG.

```
    imageAVater.apply {
        alpha = 0f
        animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000).start()
    }
```

leave the view's visibility always to visible. You can not animate a view that is gone

Comment: how do i set the positoon of the Y axis? setY??

Comment: yes either that or the setTranslationY. Check the documentation for the differences